# CreateDataSource WCF DataServices

Tags: wcf-data-services

I cant seem to figure out to get custom header that I populate on the silverlight client at the time when CreateDataSource is called.  I have the following code:

```
protected override CaseEntitiesContext CreateDataSource()
{
  return new CaseEntitiesContext(CaseGuid, ConnectionString, Provider)
  {
    DefaultContainerName = "CaseEntitiesContext"
  };
}
```

I get the ConnectionString and Provider from web.config but need to get CaseGuid from RequestHeader.

If I add the following code either in the constructor or in-line the code excutes after the CreateDataSource.

```
      ProcessingPipeline.ProcessingRequest += (o, args) =>
    {
      CaseGuid = new Guid(args.OperationContext.RequestHeaders["caseguid"]);
      Debug.WriteLine("request case guid:" + args.OperationContext.RequestHeaders["caseguid"]);
      Debug.WriteLine("CaseRequest Processing HTTP {0} request for URI {1} Case Guid {2}",
          args.OperationContext.RequestMethod,
          args.OperationContext.AbsoluteRequestUri,
          args.OperationContext.RequestHeaders["caseguid"]);
    };
```

Any ideas where / how I can get the Request object at CreateDataSource

FYI:CaseEntitiesContext is a custom constructor that creates the EF based upon Guid to determine the correct db catalog.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use HttpContext.Current.Request as the website is hosted in standard asp.net